# How to find the row that contains a specific string in GEB and in that particular row I need to select a link/checkbox

Tags: jquery, groovy, gradle, geb

Is there any way to find the row number/index that contains a specific string in GEB? I can check whether a row contains a specific string or not with:

```
text: contains()
```

But how can I find the index of that row and then click on a link in the same row using that index ID? Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated. Please don't say what did I try so far. I spent few hours already and still no way!

**EDIT:** Okay, so the problem was: I can select any row with known index, for instance:

```
$('p', 1).click()
```

but when I don't know the index of the row and in that particular row I need to select a link/checkbox, I believe this is the way we want to handle the issue, isn't it? Or is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: How can someone guess what you tried so far? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Must* you find the link by row index? If it's on the same row, why not find the row using `contains` as you suggested, then access its parent, then dive back in to find the link?

e.g. `$('p', contains('some text')).parent().find(`*the link*`).click();`

If that won't work, could you explain why you need to access it in such a manor?

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel. I will check and will get back to you, seems like that should work!

Comment: It worked fine Gabriel. Thanks a lot for the recursive way to solve the issue. Okay, so the problem was: I can select any row with known index, for instance: $('p', 1).click() but when I don't know the index of the row and in that particular row I need to select a link/checkbox, I believe this is the way we want to handle the issue, isn't it? Or is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: The way your original question was worded it sounded like you needed the index itself. Since my solution didn't use the index, I asked why you needed it, just in case it didn't work out for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle repeating content (tables/search results/etc...) in Geb is with a Module. [Example from the Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/modules.html#using_modules_for_repeating_content_on_a_page):

```
class CartRow extends Module {
    static content = {
        cell { $("td", it) }
        productName { cell(0).text() }
        quantity { cell(1).text().toInteger() }
        price { cell(2).text().toDouble() }
    }
}
```

And define a list of CartRows in our Page:

```
class CheckoutPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        cartItems { moduleList CartRow, $("table tr").tail() } // tailing to skip the header row
    }
}
```

Because the return value of cartItems is a list of CartRow instances, we can use any of the usual collection methods:

```
assert cartItems.every { it.price > 0.0 }
```

I also have a working example of this in my [Geb Examples project on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/geb-examples)...

Comment: Sorry, Brian. It was not anything related to repeating content. Actually, it was unique, I mean the opposite. Thanks for the suggestions though :)

Comment: It actually is related to repeating content. You're using a table, no? Using a module, you can get an entire row as an object. Thus, you can do away with .find, or even indexes, which can be flaky, and handle any amount of data. I know it's hard to comprehend and first but it is a better way to handle table/row data. Good luck!